# Present Simple or Present Continuous?

Tags: tense

Can we use the Present Simple in this sentence : As you know, I ***try*** to learn Chinese. Or is it better to use the Present Continuous?

Comment: What **are you trying** to say, exactly?  The two tenses mean different things.

Comment: Could you explain what  this sentence means with the Present Simple?

Comment: The simple present is used for things that you do on a consistent, regular basis (*"I **brush** my teeth every morning"*), or for things that are common or natural (*"The sun **rises** in the east"*).  The present continuous is for ongoing actions.  Note I ask what you **are trying** to ask, because that is what you are *currently* doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the verb **try**, the simple present **I try** does *not* refer to something you are doing *now, at this time in your life*. Rather, it refers to an effort you  *always* give.

You mean "now", and so for that meaning you would say **I *am trying* to learn English and chess.**

> You have decorated the place very nicely for the party!
>   -- I try.

There, **I try** means,  "I am always willing to put in a good effort. It is in my nature to try to do a good job."